# Mapping coastline geometry with SRTM raster?

Tags: raster, dem, cartography, srtm

Working on a map that includes a bathymetry layer, SRTM data for hillshade, and an accurate coastline boundary edge. I noticed though that the pixel resolution of SRTM 90m resolution creates visible blocky edges when zoomed in (this screenshot equates to z12/13 in web mercator zoom levels).

[image]

This is in Alaska, approx. latitude 57°N.

Are there any cartography or editing techniques I could use to clean this up?

Either in clipping the data or in smoothly transitioning the edges to the coastline?

Another example dataset (not SRTM but a DTM of the same area) overlaps *outside* the coastline edge, similar problem:

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the latitude. SRTM changes pixel width as you approach the poles, and this often manifests as repeated pixel values.

Comment: Added, forgot to put it there in the original post!

Comment: I would create the hillshade based on the full extent of the DEM, rather than a clipped version. Then overlay your bathymetry layer and a clean border.

Comment: If you just want to smooth the boundaries of the SRTM data, I would convert it to a binary image (ocean should be 0, land 1), then pass a smoothing kernel over the image. Finally, I'd just add the SRTM to the mask, which will effectively fill in the rough portions of the shoreline with the smooth version.

Answer (score 1):

I would say as the underlying data is a raster and therefore "blocky" if you are looking for a smooth edge you need to convert your raster into a smoothed polygon. All GIS systems allow you to convert from raster to polygon and generalise the edge. If you want to retain the hillshade then I guess you need to create a polygon dataset with a hole that is the coast and mask out the sea and layer appropriately. Well that's how I would have done it in ArcMap.

Answer (score -1):

There are better sources than SRTM Even vector data that's available. I have vector tiles of world shoreline and international boundaries.

Comment: Can you please add which data in specific and where we can find it.

Comment: http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coast  http://openstreetmapdata.com/processing/coastline

Comment: I've made raster tiles for this data and worldwide water and oceans to use as a mask for elevation data.  For the elevation tiles that I've produced from ASTER 2 GDEM and USGS NED/3DEP

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this product".